# Why is Webpack SASS-loader not transpiling SASS variables within a liner-gradient rule?

Tags: variables, webpack, sass, linear-gradients

I'm using SASS variables for colors in a .scss file. Using a single variable in a color: rule transpiles successfully:
`color: $var1`;
... however the Webpack (^4) + sass-loader (^7) transpilation complains about this rule:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $var1 0%, $var2 100%);
```

I've tried interpolation syntax, but that was unsuccessful:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #{$var1} 0%, #{$var2} 100%);
```

Also, I tried a mixin, also unsuccessful:

```
@mixin theGradient(){
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $var1 0%, $var2 100%);
}
.elementSelector {
@include theGradient();
}
```

Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: I also just tried wrapping the interpolation versions with double-quotes, no luck

Comment: An additional clue: defining the vars in the local scss file succeeds, it's only vars in a @import-ed file that fail

Answer (score 1):

I'm @import-ing a _colorVars.scss into my main scss. In my "partial" file, I removed some js comments, they were the issue. Seems as if a "partial" can't contain // comments.